# Rename Duplicates in Access with SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a table in Access, and there is one column of data that has duplicates.  I need to rename these duplicates (preferably by appending a 1, 2, 3, etc. at the end).  For example, assume my data table looks like so:

```
ID     Name               Title
1      George Washington  PRES
2      Martha Washington  FL
3      John Adams         PRES
4      Thomas Jefferson   PRES
5      Benjamin Franklin  NA
```

I want to make it look like:

```
ID     Name               Title
1      George Washington  PRES-1
2      Martha Washington  FL-1
3      John Adams         PRES-2
4      Thomas Jefferson   PRES-3
5      Benjamin Franklin  NA-1
```

I wish to accomplish with an SQL Query in Access, but I'm open to other options.  I just need to stay within Access.  I'm very new to SQL, but open to learning anything!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access `UPDATE` queries which incorporate a subquery can trigger
error #3073 (*"Operation must use an updatable query"*).

When that happens, you can try a *"domain function"* instead of the subquery to get an updatable query.  In your case, `DCount` is the appropriate domain function.

I tested this query with your sample data in Access 2010 and it did what you requested:

```sql
UPDATE YourTable AS y
SET y.Title =
    [y].[Title]
    & '-'
    & DCount("*", "YourTable", "[Title]='" & [y].[Title] & "' AND ID <= " & [y].[ID]);
```

Note you must replace *YourTable* with your table name in two places in that query.

Also note the basic concept is similar to Gordon's answer.  But it's adapted for Access.

However be aware that `DCount` and the other Access domain functions (`DSum`, `DMin`, `DMax`, `DAvg`, etc.) are not portable to other databases.

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly what I needed.  I'm not worried about portability at all, so this won't be a problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

In Access, I think you can do this with a correlated subquery in an `update`:

```
update table as t
    set title = title & '-' & (select count(*)
                               from table as t2
                               where t2.title = t.title and t2.id <= t.id
                              );
```

Comment: This looks like it would work, but I keep getting the error "Operation must use an updatable query".  I did a little research and I think it is because the count( function is read-only.  Is there a way around this?